# jquery dropdown menu with ul li issue

Tags: jquery, css, menu, html-lists

[Code tried in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BD3Kx/9/)

I am trying to create a drodown list with ul li and got blocked with issues on populating 2nd level items. Could so me one throw some idea to unblock me.

Issues: 
1. I am trying to align Country > State  > City next to each other on selection.
2. Multiple mouse over firing on items (tried with mouseenter and could not succeed).
3. Selected li item after 1st level are not shown in textbox.

```
<div><span><input type="text" id="selectText"></span><span id="toggle"> V </span></div>
<ul id="menu" style="display:none">
   <li class="level1">
    <a href="#">Country1</a>
     <ul id="ulLevel1">         
     </ul>
    </li>
   <li class="level1"><a href="#">Country2</a></li>
    <li class="level1">
    <a href="#">Country3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">State1</a></li>

</ul>

 var countries =  [
{"name": "India", "code": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Usa", "code": "AX"}, 
{"name": "China", "code": "AL"}
]
var states =  [
{"name": "Andhra", "cntrycode": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Karnataka", "cntrycode": "AX1"}, 
{"name": "Kashmir", "cntrycode": "AL"}
]
var cities =  [
{"name": "Hyderabad", "statecode": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Secbad", "statecode": "AX"}, 
{"name": "Ameerpet", "statecode": "AF"}
]

//Show hide drop down values
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
    $( "#menu" ).toggle();
    });

// Show selected value in dropdown textbox
$( "li a,li.level1 a" ).click(function() {
    $('#selectText').val('');
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $('#selectText').val(selText);
    $( "#menu" ).toggle();
    });

// populate states ul and Append inside countries li
$( "li.level1 a" ).mouseover(function() {
   var stateitems = [];
       $.each(states, function(i, stateitem) {       
          stateitems.push('<li id=level2><a href="mylink?id=' + stateitem.ID + '">' + stateitem.name + '</a>'+
                         '<ul id=ulLevel2></ul>'
                         +'  </li>');
   });

   $("#ulLevel1").append(stateitems); 

    }); 

// populate cities ul and Append inside states li

$("li").on("mouseover", "#level2 a", function() {

   var cityitems = [];
       $.each(cities, function(i, cityitem) {       
          cityitems.push('<li id=level3><a href="mylink?id=' + cityitem.ID + '">' + cityitem.name + '</a>'+
                         '<ul id=ulLevel3></ul>'
                         +' </li>');

   }); 

    $("#ulLevel2").append(cityitems);
    });

.ui-menu { width: 250px; }
ul li { background-color: gray; }
```

Comment: Please please make our life easier by next time immediately explaining what's wrong instead of letting us guess. Will not make us frustrated and help you get an answer as soon as possible ;)

Comment: So... what's wrong with this example? http://jsbin.com/aYODObu/1/edit

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. In my nested menu dropdown list, Second level items(cities) are not populated and mouse over populates first level(states) every time on mouse over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want probably something like this?

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aYODObu/4/edit)***

```
var countries =  [
{"name": "India", "code": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Usa", "code": "AX"}, 
{"name": "China", "code": "AL"}
];
var states =  [
{"name": "Andhra", "cntrycode": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Karnataka", "cntrycode": "AX1"}, 
{"name": "Kashmir", "cntrycode": "AL"}
];
var cities =  [
{"name": "Hyderabad", "statecode": "AF"}, 
{"name": "Secbad", "statecode": "AX"}, 
{"name": "Ameerpet", "statecode": "AF"}
];

// populate states ul and Append inside countries li
var stateitems = "";
$.each(states, function(i, si) {       
    stateitems += '<li id="level2"><a href="mylink?id='+ si.ID +'">'+ si.name +'</a><ul id="ulLevel2"></ul></li>';
});   
$("#ulLevel1").append(stateitems); 

// populate cities ul and Append inside states li
var cityitems = "";
$.each(cities, function(i, ci) {       
    cityitems += '<li id="level3"><a href="mylink?id='+ ci.ID +'">'+ ci.name +'</a><ul id="ulLevel3"></ul></li>';
});     
$("#ulLevel2").append(cityitems);

// ---------------------

$( "#menu" ).menu();

//Show hide drop down values
$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).toggle(); 
});

// Show selected value in dropdown textbox
$("#menu").on('click', 'li a, li.level1 a', function() {
    $('#selectText').val('');
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $('#selectText').val(selText);
    $( "#menu" ).toggle();
});
```

Comment: I am actually trying to get 3 things as per my question 1. I am trying to align Country > State > City next to each other on selection. 2. Multiple mouse over firing on items (tried with mouseenter and could not succeed). 3. Selected li item after 1st level are not shown in textbox

Answer (score 1):

You keep populating the list. This example will check first: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BD3Kx/10/)**

The change is to check:

```
 if( $("#ulLevel1").children().length == 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a menu that autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

**the input is of type search**

*I hope it is useful*

Comment: I am looking for nested menu items with ul and li that is binded to a combobox.